# input value being empty even after waiting for the value to be updated dynamically with HtmlUint3 Android

Tags: javascript, android, web-scraping, htmlunit

I use the HtmlUint3 Android library and I want to get the value of a tag element  and update it or send a value to it using JavaScript, or the value is set dynamically through JavaScript after the page loads, but when I access it through the getElementById() function, the value is always empty using the ** library, the value appears in the real browser, whether it is Android or desktop. Also, when you print the text or code, the texts that were executed through the JavaScript code appear inside the code Html.

My page has a group of frames, including the main frame, which is the page menu and controls the other frames, and there is an interconnection between them. If a frame among them is opened on another page, some information is lost. Each frame is filled with data using JavaScript, and here is the problem I face in the line below.

this code not have attribute value But it is filled out using JavaScript code. The Html code does not have a value

`<input type="text" name="IdUser" id="IdUser" size="16" maxlength="64">`

work fine

`<td><script language="javascript">document.write(Info.ProductClass);</script>H738BC&nbsp;</td>`

my code

```
@SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
    fun scrapeR(){
        CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch{
            initBrowser()
            loadPage()
            loginPage()
            task()
        }
    }

    suspend fun initBrowser(){
        val browserVersion = BrowserVersion.BrowserVersionBuilder(BrowserVersion.CHROME)
        browserVersion.setSystemTimezone(TimeZone.getDefault())
        webClient = WebClient(browserVersion.build())
        // Enabled javascript
        webClient.options.isJavaScriptEnabled = true;
        webClient.options.isThrowExceptionOnScriptError = true;
        webClient.options.isThrowExceptionOnFailingStatusCode = false;
        webClient.options.isCssEnabled = true;
        webClient.javaScriptTimeout = 10000;
        webClient.options.timeout = 10000;
        webClient.ajaxController = NicelyResynchronizingAjaxController()
        webClient.options.isRedirectEnabled = true
        webClient.options.isAppletEnabled = true
        webClient.options.isUseInsecureSSL = true
        webClient.options.isWebSocketEnabled = true
        webClient.cssErrorHandler = SilentCssErrorHandler()
        webClient.refreshHandler = ThreadedRefreshHandler()
        webClient.cookieManager.isCookiesEnabled = true
        webClient.options.isDoNotTrackEnabled = true;
        webClient.options.isGeolocationEnabled = false;
        webClient.options.isPopupBlockerEnabled = false;
        webClient.options.isDownloadImages = false;
        webClient.options.isPrintContentOnFailingStatusCode = true;
    }

    suspend fun loadPage(){
        page = webClient.getPage(addressPage)
        webClient.waitForBackgroundJavaScript(1000)
    }

    // This is an independent page that works without problems
    suspend fun loginPage(){
        val inputFieldUserName = page.getElementById(usernameId) as HtmlInput
        inputFieldUserName.valueAttribute = inputUsername
        val inputFieldPassword = page.getElementById(passwordId) as HtmlInput
        inputFieldPassword.valueAttribute = inputPassword
        val butLogin = page.getElementById(buttonId) as HtmlAnchor
        page = butLogin.click()
        webClient.waitForBackgroundJavaScript(1000)
    }

    // This is another page
    suspend fun task(){
        var menuFrame = webClient.getWebWindowByName("menufrm").enclosedPage as HtmlPage
        val basicWan = menuFrame.getElementById("User_1") as HtmlAnchor
        page = basicWan.click<HtmlPage>()
        webClient.waitForBackgroundJavaScript(1000)

        var contentFrame = webClient.getWebWindowByName("contentfrm").enclosedPage as HtmlPage
        // My problem is here and when printing it appears <input type="text" name="IdUser" id="IdUser" size="16" maxlength="64">
        val basicUser = contentFrame.getElementById("IdUser") as HtmlInput
        Log.d(TAG,"result = ${basicUser.value}") // and basicWanPppUser, rawValue, defaultValue,nodeValue but empty

        webClient.setCurrentWindow(webClient.getWebWindowByName("contentfrm"))
        Log.d(TAG,(webClient.currentWindow.enclosedPage as HtmlPage).visibleText)


        for (window in webClient.webWindows) {
            if (window.enclosedPage != null) {
                val framePage = window.topWindow.enclosedPage as HtmlPage
            }
        }

    }
```

worning

```
warning: message=[Calling eval() with anything other than a primitive string value will simply return the value. Is this what you intended?] sourceName=[script in http://192.168.1.1/html/status/deviceinfo.asp from (9, 54) to (67, 10)] line=[53] lineSource=[null] lineOffset=[0]
16:45:39.726  W  warning: message=[Calling eval() with anything other than a primitive string value will simply return the value. Is this what you intended?] sourceName=[script in http://192.168.1.1/html/status/deviceinfo.asp from (9, 54) to (67, 10)] line=[50] lineSource=[null] lineOffset=[0]
16:45:39.730  W  warning: message=[Calling eval() with anything other than a primitive string value will simply return the value. Is this what you intended?] sourceName=[script in http://192.168.1.1/html/status/deviceinfo.asp from (9, 54) to (67, 10)] line=[51] lineSource=[null] lineOffset=[0]
16:45:39.735  W  warning: message=[Calling eval() with anything other than a primitive string value will simply return the value. Is this what you intended?] sourceName=[script in http://192.168.1.1/html/status/deviceinfo.asp from (9, 54) to (67, 10)] line=[52] lineSource=[null] lineOffset=[0]
16:45:39.738  W  warning: message=[Calling eval() with anything other than a primitive string value will simply return the value. Is this what you intended?] sourceName=[script in http://192.168.1.1/html/status/deviceinfo.asp from (9, 54) to (67, 10)] line=[53] lineSource=[null] lineOffset=[0]
16:45:39.757  I  Method exceeds compiler instruction limit: 39878 in int org.htmlunit.cssparser.parser.javacc.CSS3ParserTokenManager.jjMoveNfa_0(int, int)
16:45:40.088  W  Expected content type of 'application/javascript' or 'application/ecmascript' for remotely loaded JavaScript element at 'http://192.168.1.1/lang/wan.res', but got 'text/plain'.
16:45:40.139  W  Expected content type of 'application/javascript' or 'application/ecmascript' for remotely loaded JavaScript element at 'http://192.168.1.1/lang/ethenet.res', but got 'text/plain'. 
16:45:41.398  D  contentFrame HTMLElement for HtmlTextInput[<input type="text" name="IdPppUser" id="IdPppUser" size="16" maxlength="64">]
```

1 update in the code

Image

[Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0e5qv.png)

[console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gdDAx.png)

2 update in the Logcat

Comment: Is this a public page to have a chance to reproduce this?

And btw - you should use inputFieldUserName.type(inputUsername) instead of setting the attribute value.

Comment: This line `val inputFieldUserName = page.getElementById(usernameId) as HtmlInput
        inputFieldUserName.valueAttribute = inputUsername` works well and is different from this line which is the problem `val basicUser = contentFrame.getElementById("IdUser") as HtmlInput`

Comment: @RBRi The question has been updated

Comment: @RBRi page router

Comment: page router? What do you like to say?

Comment: I am trying to access this field, the router page http://192.168.0.1

Comment: Ok, this means i can to test the web page from here. So it is really hard to check what is going wrong here. Any log output about js problems.
Can you please try with a simple WebClient setup like webClient = new WebClient(); without setting any options?

Comment: @RBRi The value is still empty

Comment: @RBRi After tracking more than once that the getValue function obtains its value from the value attribute located inside the input tag. In my case, this line `<input type="text" name="IdUser" id="IdUser" size="16" maxlength="64">` does not have a value tag, so it returns an empty value. Is there a solution for that?

Comment: I think it will be better to open an HtmlUnit issue and let discuss it there.

Comment: @RBRi After several experiments with repressed, the page is launched correctly after calling the page.refresh() function, I am dealing with multiple windows so this part may be caused by webClient.fireWindowContentChanged(WebWindowEvent(webWindow, 3, oldPage, newPage))